# How manage auth token in server nodejs application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, token

I have to call some api which requires to pass token and this token is needed to refresh and the main problems is - **How and where store a token in server?** Some solution in internet tell do somethings like that (code may not works, but idea is obvious):

```
let myToken = { ... }
class MyService {
    myFunc() {
        makeHttpCall(myToken).catch(async err => {
            if (err.httpCode == 401) {
                let netToken = await refreshToken()
                myToken = netToken;
                return myFunc();
            }

        })
    }
 }
module.exports = MyService
```

And they tell that nodejs is single thread application - so there is no any issue with synchronization between calls. I agree,
but what if token is outdated and there are 2 subsequent call of `makeHttpCall` function? Yes one by one they will be failed with
`401` and let say that those calls have a delays so the order might be like that:

```
    First invocation                    
           |                                 
          \|/                                
      makeHttpCall                      Second invocation
           |                                     | 
          \|/                                   \|/ 
          401                               makeHttpCall
           |                                     |    
          \|/                                   \|/  
        refresh (unexpected delay here)         401  
           |                                     |   
           |                                    \|/  
           |                                  refresh  
          \|/                                    |
     writeNewToken                               |
           |                                     |
          \|/                                    |
       makeHttpCall                              |
           |                                     |       
          \|/                                   \|/ 
          401                             writeNewToken
(because token refreshed twice)
```

So the idea is - second `makeHttpCall` makes request just after new token is received from second invocation.

How to sync this? How to refresh token and make sure that it is not overwritten?

Please note, that question is not about any user session or oauth tokens. The solutions with session or for signing oauth is not the answer

Comment: once a token is refresh, the old one is then invalid. nothing needs to be done imho.

Comment: if anything, it's the frontend which doing things wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've been in a similar situation and the most ideal way I've found to deal with this is -

1. to wrap the everything into a master function which is responsible for refreshing the token and dispatching the requests.
2. The request should only fulfill the task of fetching data and fail gracefully if denied, letting the master function know that the tokens are no longer valid but not attempt to refresh the token itself.
3. Store the refresh token, state if it's currently being refreshed and the requests which have been dispatched. In prototype/small systems, you can store it in memory but I strongly recommend a persistent data store - sqlite, postgresql, mysql or redis with persistence enabled.

The request should never attempt to refresh the token itself because in high-throughput environments, you will quickly end up in a state where every request dispatch would refresh the token. And if a new token immediately invalidates the previous token, you'll see request succeeding or being denied randomly

Programmatically (pseudocode) -

```
let refreshToken = 'asfasfjhskajfaskf',
       isTokenBeingRefreshed = 0, //1 if it is indeed being refreshed
       pendingRequests = {      
          "<request id>":"data"
       }

function dispatchRequest(params) {       
  if(isTokenBeingRefreshed) {
     //push requests into pendingRequests and wait for token to be refreshed

  if(!isTokenBeingRefreshed) {
    //dispatch request
  }

}
```

Once you get a request to dispatch, check if the token is being refreshed. If it is, hold the request. If it's not, then dispatch the request. If the request fails, due to authentication errors, then put on hold all other requests (if already dispatched, they'll fail BUT do not request another token since one is already in progress, just silently acknowledge the request to refresh the token) and wait for token to refresh. Do distinguish if the request was denied, failed due to operational errors, due to network errors etc.

You'll probably have to use something like setInterval to dispatch requests on hold.

If you are writing this as part of a project which is going to be long term and probably high throughput, then you ought to evaluate using a message broker or a queue. Options to consider are Kafka, ZeroMQ, RabbitMQ. Even a basic home rolled queue using Redis would do the job for a decent amount of load. Check to [bull](https://optimalbits.github.io/bull/) for node.

Note - In pendingRequests, it's a good idea to store all pending, fulfilled and failed requests and their data. It's also a good idea to assign a unique id to each request so that you can try again if they fail due to authentication errors or due to network errors.